# Create a list of distinct xml items and count them xpath v1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I`m using xslt xpath v1.0 and the following xml:

```
<store>
<item>
    <title>tshirt</titlet>
</item>
<item>
    <title>shoes</titlet>
</item>
<item>
    <title>boots</titlet>
</item>
<item>
    <title>boots</titlet>
</item>
<item>
    <title>shoes</titlet>
</item>
<item>
    <title>boots</titlet>
</item>
</store>
```

The output should be a list in descending order, like:

item name (total item in the xml)

boots (3)

shoes (2)

tshirt (1)

I have found a way to identify them but cannot find a way to put the count

```
<xsl:for-each select="item[not(preceding::item/. = .)]">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pure XPath 1 that is difficult but as you use XSLT anyway you can use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to group and `xsl:sort` to sort:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

  <xsl:key name="group" match="item" use="title"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <ul>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="store/item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', title)[1])]">
                  <xsl:sort select="count(key('group', title))" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
      <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(title, ' (', count(key('group', title)), ')')"/>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQb

Answer (score 0):

You might use this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="FullXml" select="/store"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(/store/item/title/text())">
      <xsl:variable name="TheContent" select="." />
      <xsl:value-of select="$TheContent"/>(<xsl:value-of select="count($FullXml/item[title/text()=$TheContent])" />)
  </xsl:for-each>
```

With `distinct-values()` you will get a list of all values and with `.count()` you can find their number.

Comment: `distinct-values` is XPath 2, not 1.